# What is the "debugger finished with status 1"

Tags: c, debugging, codeblocks

***I defined "true" gdb.exe from minGW folder to Settings > Debugger Settings > Executable Path so, debugging problem is solved.***

I'm writing something like 2D Particle Simulator for homework with C and Glut, I have 4 headers, 2 sources. When I run the code, I see

```
Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

and I try to debugging with CodeBlocks to find where is the wrong.

Here is the debug log:

```
Active debugger config: GDB/CDB debugger:Default
Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
Selecting target: 
Debug
Adding source dir: C:\Users\emiry\Desktop\CMPE 252\Workspace\2DParticleSimulator\
Adding source dir: C:\Users\emiry\Desktop\CMPE 252\Workspace\2DParticleSimulator\
Adding file: C:\Users\emiry\Desktop\CMPE 252\Workspace\2DParticleSimulator\bin\Debug\2DParticleSimulator.exe
Changing directory to: C:/PROGRA~2/CODEBL~1/MinGW/bin
Set variable: PATH=.;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\LENOVO\easyplussdk\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Go\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts;C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35;C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%SPARK_HOME%\bin;\;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.4\bin;C:\Users\emiry\go\bin

[debug]Command-line: C:\Users\emiry\Desktop\CMPE 252\Workspace\2DParticleSimulator\bin\Debug\2DParticleSimulator.exe -nx -fullname -quiet  -args C:/Users/emiry/Desktop/CMPE25~1/WORKSP~1/2DPART~1/bin/Debug/2DPART~1.EXE
[debug]Working dir : C:\PROGRA~2\CODEBL~1\MinGW\bin

Starting debugger: C:\Users\emiry\Desktop\CMPE 252\Workspace\2DParticleSimulator\bin\Debug\2DParticleSimulator.exe -nx -fullname -quiet  -args C:/Users/emiry/Desktop/CMPE25~1/WORKSP~1/2DPART~1/bin/Debug/2DPART~1.EXE
done

[debug]> set prompt >>>>>>cb_gdb:

Setting breakpoints
Debugger finished with status 1
```

This is my first attempt debugging in my entire coding life. So, please give me clear answers, I may not understand.

main.c code

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "GL_Related.h"
#include "simulation.h"

simulation* simb;
float timeElapsed = 0;
int showGrid = 1;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    Application         application;
    GL_Window           window;
    Keys                keys;
    BOOL                isMessagePumpActive;
    MSG                 msg;
    DWORD               tickCount;

    application.className = "OpenGL";
    application.hInstance = hInstance;


    ZeroMemory(&window, sizeof(GL_Window));
    window.keys = &keys;
    window.init.application = &application;
    window.init.title = "Simulation Window";
    window.init.width = 800;
    window.init.height = 600;
    window.init.bitsPerPixel = 16;
    window.init.isFullScreen = FALSE;

    ZeroMemory(&keys, sizeof(Keys));

    if (RegisterWindowClass(&application) == FALSE)
    {

        MessageBox(HWND_DESKTOP, "Error Registering Window Class!", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return -1;
    }

    g_isProgramLooping = TRUE;
    g_createFullScreen = window.init.isFullScreen;
    while (g_isProgramLooping)
    {
        window.init.isFullScreen = g_createFullScreen;
        if (CreateWindowGL(&window) == TRUE)
        {
            if (Initialize(&window, &keys) == FALSE)
            {
                TerminateApplication(&window);
            }
            else
            {
                isMessagePumpActive = TRUE;
                while (isMessagePumpActive == TRUE)
                {
                    if (PeekMessage(&msg, window.hWnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) != 0)
                    {

                        if (msg.message != WM_QUIT)
                        {
                            DispatchMessage(&msg);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            isMessagePumpActive = FALSE;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (window.isVisible == FALSE)
                        {
                            WaitMessage();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tickCount = GetTickCount();
                            Update(tickCount - window.lastTickCount);
                            window.lastTickCount = tickCount;
                            Draw();
                            SwapBuffers(window.hDC);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            DestroyWindowGL(&window);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox(HWND_DESKTOP, "Error Creating OpenGL Window", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
            g_isProgramLooping = FALSE;
        }
    }

    UnregisterClass(application.className, application.hInstance);
    return 0;
}

void Update(DWORD ms)
{
    if (g_keys->keyDown[VK_ESCAPE] == TRUE)
        TerminateApplication(g_window);

    if (g_keys->keyDown['G'] == TRUE)
        if (showGrid == 1)
            showGrid = 0;
        else
            showGrid = 1;

    float sec = ms / 1000.0f;
    timeElapsed += sec;
    simulate(simb);
}

void Draw(void)
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluLookAt(0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    vector halfWorld;
    halfWorld.x = simb->world->x *0.5f;
    halfWorld.y = simb->world->y *0.5f;

    if (showGrid == 1)
    {
        glColor3ub(0, 0, 255);
        glLineWidth(1);
        glBegin(GL_LINES);

        for (float x = -halfWorld.x; x <= halfWorld.x; x += 1.0f)                       // x += 1.0f Stands For 1 Meter Of Space In This Example
        {
            glVertex3f(x, halfWorld.x, 0);
            glVertex3f(x, -halfWorld.x, 0);
        }

        for (float y = -halfWorld.y; y <= halfWorld.y; y += 1.0f)                       // y += 1.0f Stands For 1 Meter Of Space In This Example
        {
            glVertex3f(halfWorld.y, y, 0);
            glVertex3f(-halfWorld.y, y, 0);
        }
        glEnd();
    }


    glLineWidth(3);
    glColor3ub(0, 255, 255);

    glBegin(GL_LINES);

    glVertex3f(-10, -10, 0);
    glVertex3f(10, -10, 0);

    glVertex3f(10, -10, 0);
    glVertex3f(10, 10, 0);

    glVertex3f(10, 10, 0);
    glVertex3f(-10, 10, 0);

    glVertex3f(-10, 10, 0);
    glVertex3f(-10, -10, 0);
    glEnd();

    for (int a = 0; a < simb->nrOfParticles; a++)
    {
        vector pos = simb->particleList[a].position;
        vector color = simb->particleList[a].color;

        glColor3ub((int)color.x, (int)color.y, 0);

        glPointSize(6);
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex3f(pos.x, pos.y, 0);
        glEnd();
    }

    glColor3ub(255, 255, 255);
    glPrint(-5.0f, -13, 0, "Time elapsed (seconds): %.2f", timeElapsed);
    glPrint(-5.0f, -12, 0, "G:Grid on/off");

    glPrint(0.0f, 14, 0, "Simple Gravity System");
    glPrint(0.0f, 13, 0, "System Kinetic Energy: %.2f", simb->kineticalenergy);
    glPrint(0.0f, 12, 0, "System Potential Energy: %.2f", simb->potentialenergy);
    glPrint(0.0f, 11, 0, "System Total Energy: %.2f", (simb->kineticalenergy+simb->potentialenergy));

    glFlush();
}
```

Comment: On Windows, this error code stands for Data Execution Prevention, so I guess that your program attempted to execute code from a non-code section in memory, because for some reason, the program-counter was set to point to an address in such section.

Comment: @goodvibration Thanks, before I ask I searched and I tried to create new project with same code however program again failed with same errors. How can I fix this Data Execution Prevention?

Comment: Are you expecting me to answer this question without seeing your code?

Comment: If you're triggering DEP errors, you probably have either an invalid function pointer somewhere, or you're overflowing a buffer and smashing the stack (and thus the return address).

Comment: @goodvibration I added main code to question.

Comment: @aaaaaa123456789 Manually, I checked every pointer, I didn't find any invalid pointer before ask. After that, I decided to debugging(in the question) but I couldn't do it.

Comment: You're going too fast, you don't know enough about debugging yet to ask the right question.  Best to take the slow road, write and debug small programs first.  Assignments from a book for example.  Hopefully you'll create enough small bugs to get the hang of it, that's pretty much guaranteed.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks! At least, I found the segmentation fault.

Comment: Congratulations, first big bug slain.

Comment: OT: regarding: `float timeElapsed = 0;` this is forcing a implicit conversion from `int` to `float`.  In general, it is best to avoid such conversions.  Suggest: `float timeElapsed = 0.0f;`